# ASP.NET Label Issue

Tags: html, asp.net

I have below label in my aspx page,

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="msg"></asp:Label>
```

When it renders on page, it creates `<span>...</span>`

Is there anyway, not to generate this span tag?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a literal HTML `<label>` element:

```
<label id="lblMessage" runat="server" class="msg">...</label>
```

Because of the `runat="server"` you can still access it through the `id` in the code-behind `.cs` file.

Comment: This is the lightest answer...but it's still in a tag, it's just a <label> instead of a <span>.  It *has to be* in a tag in order to get styled - unless your desired label is within some other tag and that can be style in it's stead, or if the style isn't actually important.

Comment: @SteveBarron This is correct. I was actually under the impression he was after a `<label>` element and was inadvertently getting a `<span>` element. If you want to apply specific styling to what's wrapped in the element, or do stuff with it in the `.cs` file, the contents *will* require being wrapped in an element. What that element is solely depends on what the OP is trying to do and the context of the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The `asp:Label` control will always create a `<span>` in this case.

If you want it to not create a span you could use a literal. Lets say you wanted it to be in a div instead you could do this.

```
<div class="msg"><asp:Literal id="lblMessage" runat="server" /></div>
```

The literal just outputs the string without any html tags around it.